# I want to install git from my vpsdepot terminal ?

Tags: git, webserver

I use root to login 
I run yum install git

showing some dependency error and also this :

> There are unfinished transactions remaining. You might consider running yum-complete-transaction first to finish them.

Comment: Did u run the `yum-complete-transaction` command?

Comment: yes i did run that command

Answer (score 1):

You should do this:

`yum install yum-utils`

`yum-complete-transaction` (if this one isn't working add the `--cleanup-only` option)

`yum install git`

Yum should resolve automatically the dependencies, anyway you can try to do it manually, search for the missing packages and install them:

`yum search perl`

You should find the two missing packages: `perl-git` and `perl-dbi`, then you should install them.

Comment: git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf.x86_64 from dag has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf is needed by package git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (dag)
git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf.x86_64 from dag has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl(Git) is needed by package git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (dag)
git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf.x86_64 from dag has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl(DBI) is needed by package git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (dag)

Comment: Try to manually install the dependencies, I upgraded my answer

Comment: actually it worked with another command 

yum install git --disableexcludes=main 

bye the way thanx a lot for your help :)